# Linking form to php for captcha, linking success to form process, email sends with no body/header info

Tags: php, forms, process, linker, captcha

Working on a fairly simple form with a captcha
This is my first time dealing with captchas so I am using a prebuilt setup "quickcaptcha 1.0"

Everything currently is working fine
The form, The captcha, except for the process
I'm thinking it has to do with the amount of links I have in between the variables?

Here's what I am thinking should happen.
The form is shown to the user, and the user types in the information.
The captcha is checked after the submit button through "requestresult.php"
then if it is successful it hands it off over to "resultsettings.php" then in resultsettings it sends it to "requestprocess.php" which collected the variables in the include from the initial request.php form.

I'm not sure....right now it's sending two emails one with the body information and no input information attached, and one with nothing at all just below it.

Here's the code.

request.php:

```
<?
        /* Subject and Email Variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Request Form';
    $webMaster = 'info@mywebhost.com';

        /* Gathering Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $aliasField = $_POST['alias'];
    $cellField = $_POST['cell'];
    $emailField = str_replace( "\r\n", '', $_POST['email'] );
    $boardField = $_POST['board'];
    $refname1Field = $_POST['refname1'];
    $refcontact1Field = $_POST['refcontact1'];
    $refname2Field = $_POST['refname2'];
    $workinfoField = $_POST['workinfo'];
    $worknameField = $_POST['workname'];
    $workaddyField = $_POST['workaddy'];
    $switchnoField = $_POST['switchno'];
    $directnoField = $_POST['directno'];



        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <link href="nrlayouts.css" rel=stylesheet type=text/css />
        <script type="text/javascript">
       // <![CDATA[
        function display(obj,id1,id2) {
        txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
        if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
         document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
        }
        if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
        document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
        }
        }
        // ]]>
        </script>

        </head>
          <body bgcolor="#CCC"><form action="requestresult.php" method="post">
              <table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" align="right"><label for="name7">Full Name:</label>        </td>
                  <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="name"        id="name" />         </td>
                 </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" align="right"><label for="alias">Alias:</label></td>
                  <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" />     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" align="right"><label for="cell">Cellphone:</label>        </td>
                  <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="cell"        id="cell" />     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" align="right"><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                  <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" align="right"><label for="board">Board:</label></td>
                  <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="board" id="board" /></td>
                </tr>
                <td class="title">References?</td>
         <td class="field">
         <select name="type" onchange="display(this,'References','workinfo');">
         <option>Do you have References?:</option>
         <option value="References">Yes</option>
         <option value="workinfo">No</option>
         </select>
                </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
         <tr>
         <td class="title">Please Prove You are Human:  <img          src="quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php" border="1"></td>
          <td><input MAXLENGTH=8 SIZE=8 name="userstring" type="text" value=""></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="align-center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email!" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
          </tr>
          </tfoot>
           <tbody id="References" style="display: none;">
         <tr>
         <td class="title">Reference Name:</td>
         <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refname1" size="20" maxlength="20" />        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="title">Reference Contact:</td>
           <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refcontact1" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="title">Reference Name:</td>
             <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refname2" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
           <td class="title">Reference Contact:</td>
           <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refcontact2" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
           <tbody id="workinfo" style="display: none;">
           <tr>
           <td class="title">Work Information:</td>
           <td class="field"><input type="text" name="workinfo" size="20" maxlength="30" />         </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td class="title">Employer's Name:</td>
           <td class="field"><input type="text" name="workname" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td class="title">Employer's Address:</td>
           <td class="field"><input type="textarea" name="workaddy" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="title">Main Switchboard Number:</td>
            <td class="field"><input type="text" name="switchno" size="20" maxlength="20"/>          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="title">Direct Line:</td>
                   <td class="field"><input type="text" name="directno" size="20" maxlength="20" />       </td>
             </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

requestsettings.php

```
<?php

    // This string contains allowable characters for the image.
    // To reduce confusion, zero and the letter 'o' have been removed,
    // and QuickCaptcha is NOT case-sensitive.
    $acceptedChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';

    // Number of characters in image.
    $stringlength = 5;

    // Where to go when the correct / incorrect code is entered.
    $success = "requestprocess.php";
    $failure = "failure.html";

    // A value between 0 and 100 describing how much color overlap
    // there is between text and other objects.  Lower is more
    // secure against bots, but also harder to read.
    $contrast = 60;

    // Various obfuscation techniques.
    $num_polygons = 3; // Number of triangles to draw.  0 = none
    $num_ellipses = 6;  // Number of ellipses to draw.  0 = none
    $num_lines = 0;  // Number of lines to draw.  0 = none
    $num_dots = 0;  // Number of dots to draw.  0 = none

    $min_thickness = 2;  // Minimum thickness in pixels of lines
    $max_thickness = 8;  // Maximum thickness in pixles of lines
    $min_radius = 5;  // Minimum radius in pixels of ellipses
    $max_radius = 15;  // Maximum radius in pixels of ellipses

    // How opaque should the obscuring objects be. 0 is opaque, 127
    // is transparent.
    $object_alpha = 75;
    ?>
```

requestresult.php:

```
<?php

    include "requestsettings.php";

    session_start();
    $string = strtoupper($_SESSION['string']);
    $userstring = strtoupper($_POST['userstring']); 
    session_destroy();   

    if (($string == $userstring) && (strlen($string) > 4)) {
header("Location: $success");
exit();
      } else {
header("Location: $failure");
exit();
       }
      ?>
```

requestprocess.php

```
<?php
      include_once "request.php";

$emailSubject = 'Request Form';
$webMaster = 'info@mywebhost.com';


$body = <<<EOD
   <br><hr><br>
  Name: $nameField <br>
  Alias: $aliasField <br>
  Cellphone: $cellField <br>
  Email: $emailField <br>
  Board: $boardField <br>
  Reference Name1: $refname1Field <br>
  Reference Contact1: $refcontact1Field <br>
  Reference Name2: $refname2Field <br>
  Reference Contact2: $refcontact2Field <br>
  Work Information: $workinfoField <br>
  Work Name: $worknameField <br>
  Work Address: $workaddyField <br>
  Switchboard Number: $switchnoField <br>
  Direct Line: $directnoField <br>
    EOD;

$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

      /* Results rendered as HTML */
     $result = "Thank you!  Your request will be answered shortly.";
        if($success){
echo "$result";
      }else{
echo "There was an error with your submission";
exit;
      }
     ?>
```

imagebuilder.php

```
<?php
include "settings.php";

// Keep #'s reasonable.
$min_thickness = max(1,$min_thickness);
$max_thickness = min(20,$max_thickness);
// Make radii into height/width
$min_radius *= 2;
$max_radius *= 2;
// Renormalize contrast
$contrast = 255 * ($contrast / 100.0);
$o_contrast = 1.3 * $contrast;

$width = 15 * imagefontwidth (5);
$height = 2.5 * imagefontheight (5);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
imagealphablending($image, true);
$black = imagecolorallocatealpha($image,0,0,0,0);

// Build the  validation string
$max = strlen($acceptedChars)-1;
$password = NULL;
for($i=0; $i < $stringlength; $i++) {
    $cnum[$i] = $acceptedChars{mt_rand(0, $max)};
    $password .= $cnum[$i];
}

// Add string to image
$rotated = imagecreatetruecolor (70, 70);
$x = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $stringlength; $i++) {
    $buffer = imagecreatetruecolor (20, 20);
    $buffer2 = imagecreatetruecolor (40, 40);

    // Get a random color
    $red = mt_rand(0,255);
    $green = mt_rand(0,255);
    $blue = 255 - sqrt($red * $red + $green * $green);
    $color = imagecolorallocate ($buffer, $red, $green, $blue);

    // Create character
    imagestring($buffer, 5, 0, 0, $cnum[$i], $color);

    // Resize character
    imagecopyresized ($buffer2, $buffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25 + mt_rand(0,12), 25 + mt_rand(0,12), 20, 20);

    // Rotate characters a little
    $rotated = imagerotate($buffer2, mt_rand(-25, 25),imagecolorallocatealpha($buffer2,0,0,0,0)); 
    imagecolortransparent ($rotated, imagecolorallocatealpha($rotated,0,0,0,0));

    // Move characters around a little
    $y = mt_rand(1, 3);
    $x += mt_rand(2, 6); 
    imagecopymerge ($image, $rotated, $x, $y, 0, 0, 40, 40, 100);
    $x += 22;

    imagedestroy ($buffer); 
    imagedestroy ($buffer2); 
}

// Draw polygons
if ($num_polygons > 0) for ($i = 0; $i < $num_polygons; $i++) {
    $vertices = array (
        mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25),mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25),
        mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25),mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25),
        mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25),mt_rand(-0.25*$width,$width*1.25)
    );
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), $object_alpha);
    imagefilledpolygon($image, $vertices, 3, $color);  
}

// Draw random circles
if ($num_ellipses > 0) for ($i = 0; $i < $num_ellipses; $i++) {
    $x1 = mt_rand(0,$width);
    $y1 = mt_rand(0,$height);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), $object_alpha);
//  $color = imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast));
    imagefilledellipse($image, $x1, $y1, mt_rand($min_radius,$max_radius), mt_rand($min_radius,$max_radius), $color);  
}

// Draw random lines
if ($num_lines > 0) for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++) {
    $x1 = mt_rand(-$width*0.25,$width*1.25);
    $y1 = mt_rand(-$height*0.25,$height*1.25);
    $x2 = mt_rand(-$width*0.25,$width*1.25);
    $y2 = mt_rand(-$height*0.25,$height*1.25);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), $object_alpha);
    imagesetthickness ($image, mt_rand($min_thickness,$max_thickness));
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2 , $color);  
}

// Draw random dots
if ($num_dots > 0) for ($i = 0; $i < $num_dots; $i++) {
    $x1 = mt_rand(0,$width);
    $y1 = mt_rand(0,$height);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast), mt_rand(0,$o_contrast),$object_alpha);
    imagesetpixel($image, $x1, $y1, $color);
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['string'] = $password;

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in having 2 duplicate `$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);` might be what's going wrong. Have you tried setting one as `$success1...` and `$success2...` ?

Comment: And, without the `imagebuilder.php` source, I am unable to test it for you.

Comment: I removed the top $success = mail() and it only sent one email but I still get no info.

Comment: I figured since the $result is displayed, and the email sends that the captcha runs fine...but I will post it if you like.

Comment: It's ok, I'll need the entire library files. I downloaded them now and will see what I can do for you.

Comment: This needs a whole new overhaul. I've got it working, but stripped down. I can submit an answer, but don't downvote me if it doesn't work the way you want it to. I had to take out the `$result = "Thank you! Your request will be answered shortly.";` etc. in requestprocess.php file. You could then take it from there and work with copies, while keeping my original codes.

Comment: Can you inbox it to me?  I'll update the code or close the question.  I just got downvoted on my question for being a noob apparently.

Comment: I doubt we can inbox each other. I'll just post my answer, then you can delete the question.

Comment: Check my answer below. It worked fine for me, along with field names coming in message via email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified form (request.php) - 
**NOTE:** Be sure to modify path to imagebuilder.php file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link href="nrlayouts.css" rel=stylesheet type=text/css />
    <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
    function display(obj,id1,id2) {
    txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
    if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
     document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
    }
    }
    // ]]>
    </script>

    </head>
      <body bgcolor="#CCC">
          <table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
<form action="requestprocess.php" method="post">
            <tr>
              <td width="250" align="right"><label for="name7">Full Name:</label>        </td>
              <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="name"        id="name" />         </td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="250" align="right"><label for="alias">Alias:</label></td>
              <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" />     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="250" align="right"><label for="cell">Cellphone:</label>        </td>
              <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="cell"        id="cell" />     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="250" align="right"><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
              <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="250" align="right"><label for="board">Board:</label></td>
              <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" name="board" id="board" /></td>
            </tr>
            <td class="title">References?</td>
     <td class="field">
     <select name="type" onchange="display(this,'References','workinfo');">
     <option>Do you have References?:</option>
     <option value="References">Yes</option>
     <option value="workinfo">No</option>
     </select>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
     <tr>
     <td class="title">Please Prove You are Human:  <img src="imagebuilder.php" border="1"></td>
      <td><input MAXLENGTH=8 SIZE=8 name="userstring" type="text" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="align-center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email!" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
       <tbody id="References" style="display: none;">
     <tr>
     <td class="title">Reference Name:</td>
     <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refname1" size="20" maxlength="20" />        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="title">Reference Contact:</td>
       <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refcontact1" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="title">Reference Name:</td>
         <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refname2" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
       <td class="title">Reference Contact:</td>
       <td class="field"><input type="text" name="refcontact2" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody id="workinfo" style="display: none;">
       <tr>
       <td class="title">Work Information:</td>
       <td class="field"><input type="text" name="workinfo" size="20" maxlength="30" />         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="title">Employer's Name:</td>
       <td class="field"><input type="text" name="workname" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="title">Employer's Address:</td>
       <td class="field"><input type="textarea" name="workaddy" size="20" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Main Switchboard Number:</td>
        <td class="field"><input type="text" name="switchno" size="20" maxlength="20"/>          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Direct Line:</td>
               <td class="field"><input type="text" name="directno" size="20" maxlength="20" />       </td>
         </tr>
        </form>
          </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Here is the modified process (requestprocess.php)

```
<?php

$emailSubject = 'Request Form';
$webMaster = 'youremail@somewhere.com';

        /* Gathering Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $aliasField = $_POST['alias'];
    $cellField = $_POST['cell'];
    $emailField = str_replace( "\r\n", '', $_POST['email'] );
    $boardField = $_POST['board'];
    $refname1Field = $_POST['refname1'];
    $refcontact1Field = $_POST['refcontact1'];
    $refname2Field = $_POST['refname2'];
    $workinfoField = $_POST['workinfo'];
    $worknameField = $_POST['workname'];
    $workaddyField = $_POST['workaddy'];
    $switchnoField = $_POST['switchno'];
    $directnoField = $_POST['directno'];

$body = "
   <br><hr><br>
  Name: $nameField <br>
  Alias: $aliasField <br>
  Cellphone: $cellField <br>
  Email: $emailField <br>
  Board: $boardField <br>
  Reference Name1: $refname1Field <br>
  Reference Contact1: $refcontact1Field <br>
  Reference Name2: $refname2Field <br>
  Reference Contact2: $refcontact2Field <br>
  Work Information: $workinfoField <br>
  Work Name: $worknameField <br>
  Work Address: $workaddyField <br>
  Switchboard Number: $switchnoField <br>
  Direct Line: $directnoField <br>
";


$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

      /* Results rendered as HTML */
     $result = "Thank you! Your request will be answered shortly.";

// NOTE: produces an error, commented out
//        if($success){
echo "$result";
//      }else{
//echo "There was an error with your submission";
//exit;
//      }

?>
```

Here is requestsettings.php (modified line 14, $success=...etc)

```
<?php

// This string contains allowable characters for the image.
// To reduce confusion, zero and the letter 'o' have been removed,
// and QuickCaptcha is NOT case-sensitive.
$acceptedChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';

// Number of characters in image.
$stringlength = 5;

// Where to go when the correct / incorrect code is entered.
//    $success = "requestprocess.php";

$success = "success.html";
$failure = "failure.html";

// A value between 0 and 100 describing how much color overlap
// there is between text and other objects.  Lower is more
// secure against bots, but also harder to read.
$contrast = 60;

// Various obfuscation techniques.
$num_polygons = 3; // Number of triangles to draw.  0 = none
$num_ellipses = 6;  // Number of ellipses to draw.  0 = none
$num_lines = 0;  // Number of lines to draw.  0 = none
$num_dots = 0;  // Number of dots to draw.  0 = none

$min_thickness = 2;  // Minimum thickness in pixels of lines
$max_thickness = 8;  // Maximum thickness in pixles of lines
$min_radius = 5;  // Minimum radius in pixels of ellipses
$max_radius = 15;  // Maximum radius in pixels of ellipses

// How opaque should the obscuring objects be. 0 is opaque, 127
// is transparent.
$object_alpha = 75;
?>
```

I changed some of the files. You can modify them to your liking, but work with copies to test. Let me know how it works out for you, it worked for me.

Comment: Wow. I thought I had that before I moved my variables back to request.php but it wasn't working.  Somehow now it is.  Thank you.

Comment: @Chickpea Right on, am glad it worked out for you, cheers ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: @Chickpea One thing that was giving me an error was the `$body = <<<EOD` I changed it to `$body = "` with closing `";` in the `requestprocess.php` file.